# Minitab - Individual Value Plot - How to Add Legend

Tags: plot, legend, minitab

using Minitab I'm trying to create an individual value plot (one y, with groups) including a legend. It seems like such an option is not available. If infact it is can you please help me find it?

Further I tried to substitue using a legend by adding 'add data labels', 'individual data', 'use labels from column'. This gives me the indication of which data point belongs to which batch (e.g. 1286443, see figure attatched). However, the labels overlap each other. Can this be avoided other than by manually dislocating the data leabels?

Kind regards,
Timon

[image: Individual Value Plot without Legend]

[image]